# React TypeScript: How to userReducer with two different contexts?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

On the Home page, I want to be able to change the language, to 'kr' from the default 'en'. I've made the button click call a function and I then change the context which in turn calls the reducer, is this the right way?

Also when I use the reducer am I mutating the state or not?

How do I apply types to the action in the reducer and the default state?

```
import React, { useReducer } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { setGlobalContext, globalContext } from "./components/context";
import { Layout } from "./components/layout";
import { Home } from './routes/home';
import { NotFound } from './routes/not-found';
import { globalReducer } from './components/reducer'

const Router: React.FC = () => {

  const [global, setGlobal] = useReducer(globalReducer, {
    language: 'en',
  })

  return (
    <setGlobalContext.Provider value={{ setGlobal }}>
      <globalContext.Provider value={{ global }}>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <Route render={({ location }) => (
            <Layout location={ location }>
              <Switch location={ location }>
                <Route exact path = '/' component = { Home } />
                <Route component = { NotFound }/>
              </Switch>
            </Layout>
          )} />
        </BrowserRouter>
      </globalContext.Provider>
    </setGlobalContext.Provider>
  );
}

export { Router };
```

./components/reducer looks like

```
const CHANGE_LANGUAGE = 'CHANGE_LANGUAGE';
const globalReducer = (state: any, action: any) => {

    switch (action.type) {
        case CHANGE_LANGUAGE:
            return {...state, 
                language: action.value
            }
        default:
            return state
    }
}

export { globalReducer, CHANGE_LANGUAGE }
```

and ./components/context

```
import React from "react";
const setGlobalContext = React.createContext({});
const globalContext = React.createContext({});
export { setGlobalContext, globalContext };
```

and ./routes/home

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useRef, useState} from 'react';
import { setGlobalContext, globalContext } from "./context";
import { CHANGE_LANGUAGE } from './components/reducer'

const Home: React.FC<propsInterface> = (props) => {
  const { global } = useContext(globalContext) as {global: any};
  const { setGlobal } = useContext(setGlobalContext) as {setGlobal: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<any>>};

const changeLanguage = () => {
  setGlobal({type: CHANGE_LANGUAGE, value: 'kr'})
}

  return (
    <button onClick={changeLanguage}>Change language to Korean<button>
  )
}
export { Home };
```

Comment: `const [globalState, dispatch] = useReducer(globalReducer, globalState)` is a syntax error because you're using `globalState` in its own declaration. You need to define your initial state, and then change the language stored in the state within the `case 'CHANGE_LANGUAGE':`

Comment: Also `return {...globalState, action.value}` is a syntax error. You're missing the key.

Comment: should it be like `return {...globalState, language: action.value};`